# Visual Basic '15 combo box text to a lable

Tags: vb.net, combobox

So basically, I want to be able to send all my text items in a combo box to a label on a different form to print it.

Here is my code snippet;

```
        '   Shows the yacht types in a new called frmYachtTypeSummary which then can be printed
    frmYachtTypeSummary.lblYachtTypeSummary.Text = cboYachtType.Text.ToString
    frmYachtTypeSummary.ShowDialog()
```

When I use what I have here, if I select an object in the combo box it prints to the desired form. What I want to do though, is have the entire combo box print to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim allItems as String, item as Object
For Each item In cboYachtType.Items
    allItems = allItems & item.toString() & vbCrLf
Next
frmYachtTypeSummary.lblYachtTypeSummary.Text = allItems
```

p.s.: this answer started as a VBA answer but it appeared that the OP had a tag error.

Comment: I tried using the code you gave me, and it told me that allItems is being used before it is declared.                                        Also, you are right, I do not know exactly what one I am using because I am still getting used to it. I know it is through Visual Studio and the class is Visual Basic. I am creating window forms too.

Comment: You are definitely on VB.Net. `Dim allItems as String = "", item as Variant`. Also try `.Text` in place of `.Caption`.
`

Comment: First, I want to say thank you for all the help you are giving me. So I tried the code again, but Variant is not coming up. The closest thing to it, is  VariantType  which makes me get an error on my cboYachtType.Text

Comment: @S.Jeff try the last modification

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! So now I have to ask, where do I find something like this? I searched on the internet but couldn't find an exact answer.

Comment: @S.Jeff you are welcome. MSDN is full of resources on this matter, as well as many *"vb.net forms"* tutorials and books.